# How do I get my nav menu to show sub pages?

Tags: functions, jquery, javascript, sub-menu, menus

http://webdesignsalemoregon.com/westernmennoniteschool/ is my website.

I've got the top menu which is the one that was in the theme when I started to customize it. It's got a test drop down that works just fine. I included a secondary menu under the slider with this code

```
<div id="secondaryMenu">
    <?php
        $menuID = 'bottom-nav';
        $footerNav = '';

        if (function_exists('wp_nav_menu')) $footerNav = wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'footer-menu', 'container' => '', 'fallback_cb' => '', 'menu_id' => $menuID, 'menu_class' => 'bottom-nav', 'echo' => false, 'depth' => '2' ) );
        if ($footerNav == '') show_page_menu($menuID);
        else echo($footerNav);
    ?>
</div>
```

It works just fine, except for the fact it does NOT show drop downs? I've got 3 pages underneath "Admissions" the furthest left item, and they don't show up?

Comment: Have you viewed source? Are they showing, but css is hiding them? A link to the site with this issue would be extremely helpful in troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First let me start by stating the @cale_b is probebaly right and you should first look at your css / jquery to ensure that your items arnt being hidden...

Also - you should change this:

```
'depth' => '2'
```

To this:

```
'depth' => 0
```

0 = show all & no need to surround it like this: '0' This is the right way 'depth' => 0
(since its not a string.)

Hope this Helps,
Cheers, Sagive.

Comment: I actually just ended up figuring out I could use the jQuery Superfish function on that whole element, and it worked just fine, lol. Thanks though!

Comment: glad you got it working :)

Comment: tip: you should fix your question to show solution and mark it answerd ;)